# How to fit "Buttons" into frame using "table row"?

Tags: android, button, tablerow, android-tablelayout

I'm making a calculator but inside frame, it's not fitting.

I'm using "Table Layout" inside it.

but it's showing this.

[image]

While I wanted to make like this.

[image]

please help, how to fix my button proper inside frame? thanks.

Here is my source code for "button".

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#cccccc" 
        android:padding="15dp"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <TableRow>
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="7"/>

             <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:text="8"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btn9"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="9"
                 android:layout_weight="1"/>

             <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="÷"
                 android:layout_weight="1"/>     
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5"
                android:weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6"
                android:weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7"
                android:weight="1"/>

       </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the last 3 buttons' xml, you write **android:weight="1"** which will be **android:layout_weight="1"**

```
    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

   </TableRow>
```